# TextView size differs in real device and emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, textview

None of the previously asked questions and solutions worked for me.

For the methods setTextSize(), when I give hard coded value as below:

```
textView.setTextSize(16)
```

the text appears to be of same size on emulator and device.

However, when I give the size in dimensions file:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="default_text_size">5sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and I have tried 2 approaches programatically for setting this size:

```
defaultTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_text_size));
```

and

```
defaultTextView.setTextSize(getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_text_size));
```

Both of them show different size on real device and on emulator.

Please see attached screenshots.

Any idea how to fix this issue? I know that it will change based upon the screen resolution, but this is drastic change. The whole text has shrunk in the upper half of the ListView row in case of emulator. Which is not what I want.

[image: Emulator]

[image: Real Device]

Comment: Can you check that both devices don't have any scale factor in settings for font size?

Comment: Thanks. This was one of the factors and I sorted it out using layout_weight. Now the text is not shrinking to the upper half.

Answer (score 1):

> Scale-independent Pixels (sp) - this is like the dp unit, but it is
>   **also scaled by the user's font size preference**. It is recommended you
>   use this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for
>   both the screen density and user's preference.

When you set the size unit of text (in TextView) as **sp** it becomes also dependent on the user/device font size preference. For this reason, on different devices your text may appear different.

If you want your text to appear everywhere same (regardless of the user's font size preference), use **dp** instead:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="default_text_size">5dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I wanted it to scale based upon the screen size but the issue was that the text was shrinking up to the upper half. I gave them equal layout_weight and it is working now. Thanks

Comment: @Manpreet - I'm glad that you've found a solution.